# Replace many parts of a string python3

Tags: html, string, python-3.x, urllib

Via the modules urllib and re I am attempting to scrape a web page for it's text content. I'm following a guide provided by "SentDex" on youtube found here ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEshegZzt3M ) and the documentation with the official Python site to cobble together a quick solution. The information that comes back has plenty of HTML markup and special characters that I am trying to remove. My end result is successful but I feel that it is hard coded solution and is only useful for this one scenario.

The code is as follows :

```
url = "http://someUrl.com/dir/doc.html" #Target URL

values = {'s':'basics',
        'submit':'search'} #Set parameters for later use

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values) #Really not sure...

data = data.encode('utf-8') #set to UTF-8

req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)#Arrange the request parameters 

resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)#Get the document's contents matching that data type from that URL

respData = resp.read() #read the content into a variable
#BS4 method
soup = BeautifulSoup(respData, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all("p")
#end BS4
#re method
text = re.findall(r"<p>(.*?)</p>",str(respData)) #get all paragraph tag contents
text = str(text) #convert it to a string 
#end re
conds = ["<b>","</b>","<i>","</i>","\\","[","]","\'"] #things to remove from text

for case in conds:#for each of those things

    text = text.replace(case,"") #remove string AKA replace with nothing
```

Are there more effective ways to achieve the end goal of removing all "Markup" from a string further than explicit definitions of each condition?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah don't use regex to parse html.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ regex is pretty new territory to me so please do elaborate if possible so I better understand the tool I am using :) I find that the Python documentation language is a bit... dense and difficult to discern at times.

Comment: I would recommend looking at beautiful soup or lxml.

Comment: Alrighty, I will give them a try.

Comment: I am finding similar results, I still have to go through and do my replacement loop in order to clear out all the markup. I'll update the question to add the updated method of collecting the raw information.